# Charge on grounded conducting sphere in uniform E-field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electricity

- How does one deal with a grounded conducting sphere in uniform electric field ie-what is the charge distribution on the sphere?
- If two charged conducting spheres are in each other's electric field then will the field of one affect the electric potential inside the second sphere?

Answer (score 2):

In order to find the potential function, one usually employs the methods used [here](http://www.physicspages.com/2012/04/05/sphere-in-uniform-field-via-method-of-images/). Then, once you have this function for the potential:

$V(r)=\frac{2q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 a^2}(r-\frac{R^3}{r^2})cos(\theta)$

Find the electric field at the surface of the grounded sphere of radius R

$E(R)=\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial r}\bigg|_{r=R}=\frac{2q*cos(\theta)}{4\pi\epsilon_0 a^2}*3=\frac{6q*cos(\theta)}{4\pi\epsilon_0 a^2}$

$\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}=E(R)
$

$\Rightarrow \sigma=\frac{6q*cos(\theta)}{4\pi a^2}$

That should answer your first question.

As for your second question, no, the potential inside each sphere will not change. Why?

Let's see what happens when a charged sphere is brought near another charged conducting sphere, or really *any* charge configuration changes the electric field in the environment of the charged conductiong sphere in question. The elctric field everywhere will **change** (except, of course inside the sphere) and there are lots of nifty tricks to figure out the new electric field, the method of image charges being the most prominent. Now, consider a regular conducting sphere with a charge q and a radius R sitting somewhere with no external fields. The potential at its surface and inside it $=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0R}$, a constant. That means that you can add this constant to the (new) potential function for the region outside without changing the electric field outside, because the gradient of a constant is $0$. Now, inside the sphere, $E=0$, which means the potential inside is a constant function (gradient of a constant is zero). You can set that constant to be whatever you want and  $=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0R}$ looks pretty good, unless you want a discontinuity in the potential function.

Answer (score 0):

The most analytical way to face the problem of the conducting sphere in a uniform field is solving the Laplace's equation for the potential - $\nabla^2V=0$, which comes immediately from Gauss' law in free space, $\vec\nabla.\vec{E}=\rho/\epsilon_0$, along with the definition of the potential, $\vec{E}=-\vec\nabla{V}$. Solving Laplace's equation is a well known important problem and, after that, all that's left is applying the boundaries conditions for the specific problem, refining the general solution. See, for example, [this article](https://faculty.washington.edu/seattle/physics227/reading/conducting-sphere.pdf).

The potential inside the second sphere won't change ultimately. The physical reason is that, since it's a conducting material, the electrostatic condition forbids the existence of a non-zero field inside the sphere because, if there was one, the free charges (of a conducting material) would move and this wouldn't be electrostatics. That's why the whole sphere must be an equipotential, since if there was a variation in the potential within the sphere there would be a resulting field in some point. In fact, would be enough knowing that the surface of the sphere (a shell) is an equipotential because there's a general property of the Laplace's equation solutions: they don't admit local minima or maxima. And, more than that, since the sphere is grounded its potential is, by definition, $0$.